# list all the columns used in proc with respective table name

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am looking for a logic to find all the column names used inside procedure block with respective table. We have 100's of proc so listing all manually will be very difficult.

for Ex: 
a dynamic query in one of proc is

```
v_sql := ' insert into table1 
  select a.column1 , b.column1 from srctbl1 a,srctbl2 b where a.id=b.id'

execute immediate v_sql
```

Is there any way to get result like

```
table    column
srctbl1  column1
srctbl1  id
srctbl2  column1
srctbl2  id
```

Comment: you can write it  in procedure, you can write sql parser

Comment: With static SQL you might get somewhere with [PL/Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adfns/plscope.html); but what dynamic SQL will do and reference is opaque to Oracle until runtime - that's the point, really. Your example doesn't need to be dynamic anyway, and in principle you could parse the details out - though it would be painful and error-prone. Generally for legitimately dynamic SQL the table or column names would probably be variables, which again wouldn't be known until runtime.

Comment: PL/SCOPE can identify static SQL statements but you would still need to parse the statements to extract the table and column names.

Comment: not an expert on this but wondering that using  `all_source` and `all_tab_columns`  in join and  search for columns name in `text` column of `all_source` table would give table and column names mentioned in procedure text.

Comment: And you want to create this list of table columns because... ?

Comment: Hi All,  is there any way i can get the details(column level details) from executing query from gv$sql?

Answer (score 0):

I have to post as answer as cannot format code in comment. @RamaSh, while on the surface a join may initially seem a viable solution it really isn't. Joining all_source to all_tab_columns would not work.

Consider the the following single static query. In that query there is not a single reference for table_name.column.name as tables are all aliased and columns referenced by the alias, and some "columns" that simply do not exist outside the scope of the query. Further in all_source this statement requires 13 rows. Now image trying with a 3000-4000 line package.

```
select customer, account_number
     , purchases_total,  payments_total, purchased_total - payments_total net_change
  from (
        select cust.name customer, cust.account_number
             , sum(pur.amt) purchased_total, sum(pay.amount) payments_total 
          from customers  cust
          join customer_orders pur on (pur.cust_id = cust.cust_id)
          join customer_payments pay on (pay.cust_id = cust.cust_id)    
         where trunc(pur.activity_date) > trunc(sysdate-31)
           and trunc(pay.activity_date) > trunc(sysdate-31)
         group by cust.name, cust.account_number
       ) 
   order by purchased_total - payments_total desc;
```

This doesn't even begin to approach the problems with dynamic sql with execute immediate nor the potentially much more complicated dbms_sql;

Answer (score 0):

Making such a procedure to find columns from procedure code is really difficult task as query can include lots of keywords other than just select and from, what I can tell you is that you can find tables used in procedures, below procedure puts referenced table names in newly created table temp123456:

```
set serveroutput on;

  declare
  cursor c1 is select distinct(name) from user_source 
  where type='PROCEDURE';
  begin

  execute immediate 'create table temp123456 as select 
  select 
    referenced_owner, 
    referenced_name, 
    referenced_type
  from 
    dba_dependencies
  where rownum<1';
  for i in c1
  loop

  insert into temp123456(referenced_owner, 
    referenced_name, 
    referenced_type)  
    select 
    referenced_owner, 
    referenced_name, 
    referenced_type
  from 
    dba_dependencies
  where 
    name= i.name;
  and 
    owner = 'SCHEMA_OWNER'
  order by 
    referenced_owner, referenced_name, referenced_type; 
  end loop;
  end;
```